# Is there an efficient way to underline sample mean values in RMarkdown when attempting to construct diagram for Tukey's Procedure?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I am currently attempting to complete an RMarkdown document that requires the use of Tukey's Method, where sample means are compared by underlining them. Is there any efficient way to underline the sample means to get something similar to

[image]

but will allow for multiple underlines across different sample means. The issue I am running into is when something has been underlined already, but needs to be underlined a second our third time while still neatly showing that it corresponds to another sample mean that has also been underlined and joined to one of the other sample means. I have tried nesting \underline, but am unable to get a neat result that clearly represents the variance in the sample means. The goal I am trying to achieve is to attach the 1st two samples, then separately attach the 2nd two samples with their own line, then the 3rd and 4th with their own line, and then the last two samples with their own line as well. Any help is greatly appreciated.